# find -print0 | xargs -0 grep not working as expected on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: shell, find, xargs

I've got a bit of a weird issue.

If I run:

```
find . -iname '*.php' -o -iname '*.pl' -o -iname '*.html' | xargs grep -i users
```

I get a load of errors for filenames containing spaces, but also some files match.

However, if I try the following so filenames with spaces in are correctly handled, no matches are returned:

```
find . -iname '*.php' -o -iname '*.pl' -o -iname '*.html' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i users
```

What am I doing wrong? The second command should return me at least the same matching files as the first, but I don't get any matches.

Comment: Why don't you just add `-exec grep -i users {} \;` instead of using `xargs` ?

Comment: It still doesn't work. It works without the additional -o -iname '*.pl' -o -iname '*.html' clause though

Answer (score 3):

And the answer is:

```
find . \( -iname '*.php' -o -iname '*.pl' -o -iname '*.html' \) -print0 | xargs -r0 grep -i users
```

This works. I hadn't seen it before but a colleague told me about it.

Comment: Or `-iname '*.php' -print0 -o -iname '*.pl' -print0 ...`...

Comment: You could also use `\( -iname '*.php' ... \) -exec grep -i users +`, where the plus means 'build up a command line like `xargs` without needing to use `xargs`'.  Using a semi-colon `\;` would mean execute `grep` for each file as it is found.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need print0 and xargs, this functionality is already built in find:

```
find . -iname "*.php" -o -iname "*.pl" -o -iname "*.html" -exec grep -i users {} +
```